# Why do I have to export the function I use in angular appModule import module?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following code

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    RoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        tokenGetter: () => localStorage.getItem('token’), // <———— this line has problem
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4200']
        //blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:3001/auth/', 'foo.com/bar/']
      }
    })
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It works using `ng serve`, but I got following error when I run `ng build --prod`

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'ɵ0'
    'ɵ0' contains the error at app/app.module.ts(36,22)
      Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

Then I modified my code to

```js
function getToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token')
}
…
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        headerName: 'Authorization',
        tokenGetter: () => getToken, 
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4200’]
...
```

And it's still not happy

```
ERROR in app/app.module.ts(19,10): Error during template compile of 
'AppModule'
  Reference to a non-exported function.
```

At the end, I solved the issue by exporting the `getToken` function.

I have following question

1. Why `ng serve` works but not `ng build --prod`?
2. Why inline lambda doesn't work?
3. Why do I have to export the function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issues you are having are due to the [Ahead-of-Time (AOT)](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) compiler in Angular. By default, `ng serve` and `ng build` use the Just-in-Time (JIT) compiler. However, `ng build --prod` uses the AOT compiler. You can simulate this same behavior doing `ng serve --aot`.

So, to your questions.

1. See above explanation.
2. The AOT Collector does not support the arrow
   function
   [syntax](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax).
3. Angular generates a class factory in a separate module and that
   factory can only access [exported
   functions](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#exported-symbols).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you this helps so much and explains a lot. Happy :)